# Mysql query random order (pause and continue) question

Tags: mysql

Okay i am trying to create a mysql query that does this:
show 3 random records from table then after the 3th record show TEXT
and then show the same 3 items but other field (equaling to the items ofcourse) from same table.

### eg table info:

```
--ids | titles------

10   | one

20   | two

30   | three
```

and the query results from the given example:

```
30 10 20  TEXT three one two
```

if anyone understand what i am asking,post your suggestion/asnwer
thanks for your time all :)

Comment: `What is 30 10 20 TEXT three one two? You want a single row result with 7 columns?` (and if so why do you care what order the columns are in)

Comment: the 30 10 20 TEXT three one two is how i want to look an example random query i want the ids in random then show some text (pause the query) and then the same query but show 3 names (the 3ids's names)

Answer (score 1):

Just for kicks..

```
select t1.id, t2.id, t3.id, 'TEXT', t1.title, t2.title, t3.title
FROM
(
    select @r := @r + 1 rownum, id
    from (select @r:=0) initvar, (
        select id
        from tbl
        order by rand()
        limit 3
    ) X
) Y
join tbl t1 on Y.rownum=1 and t1.id = Y.id
join tbl t2 on Y.rownum=2 and t2.id = Y.id
join tbl t3 on Y.rownum=3 and t3.id = Y.id
```

You should really just do the query below, and do whatever display processing using the 3 rows returned, in whatever programming environment you use (Java/PHP/.Net etc).

```
select id, title
from tbl
order by rand()
limit 3
```

---

### EDIT

To get the data in 7 different ***rows***, you can use the below. I stress again that this is front-end display code. I will not use such SQL code in a production system.

```
select display
from
(
select sorter, rownum,
    case when sorter=3 then title else id end display
from
(
    select @r := @r + 1 rownum, id, title
    from (select @r:=0) initvar,
    (
        select id, title
        from tbl
        order by rand()
        limit 3
    ) X
) Y, (select 1 sorter union all select 3) dup
union all
select 2, 0, 'TEXT'
) Z
order by sorter, rownum
```

Example Output

```
7
2
1
TEXT
test 7    << title for id=7
test 2
test 1
```

Comment: I use the similar query but the problem is that after the 3 items returned i want to add some text just once and then show the same 3 random results but different rows...
i hope u get what i am sayin now :)

Comment: @ivo / You would get a lot more traction if you just asked how to do this in the front end, because that's where this should be done